# How do I target siblings in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selector

I'm creating a toggle review form that displays when you hit Edit, but I only want this to work on on the review the button is a sibling of, as opposed to all review edit forms on the page (as there may be multiple).

I know how to do this in jquery but am trying to keep this project all vanilla js.

```
const button = document.querySelector('.toggle-edit-form');
const form = document.querySelector('.edit-review-form');
button.onclick = function() {
  // toggle the edit button text on click
  button.innerHTML === 'Edit' ? button.innerHTML = "Cancel" : button.innerHTML = "Edit";
  // toggle visibility of edit review form
  form.classList.toggle('toggle')
};
```

I could use nextSibling I suppose (as it is currently the next sibling) but would prefer a solution that won't break the code if change the order / html.

Thanks!

Comment: Add the relevant markup

Comment: _"I could use `nextSibling`...but would prefer a solution that won't break the code if change the order / html."_ - Either it's a sibling, then use `.nextSibling` or better `.nextElementSibling` or it isn't a sibling anymore.

Comment: @Andreas what's the relevant markup? In jquery siblings are all elements under a node. But here it might not necessarily be the next sibling, so I wanted code that could target it irrespective of whether it was next or not.

Comment: Let's rephase it: what have you tried so far to solve this on your own? If you already know about `.nextSibling` (and how it works, hint: `while`) then it should not be to hard to get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I don't know enough about it yet I'm afraid. I've tried a while statement, but I couldn't get to the bottom of it for my application.

Comment: Instead of 'form' use: 'button.closest('form') that will give you the form the button is on.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike you can try creating a function that uses a while loop to keep track of siblings , I hope this helps

```
var getSiblings = function (elem) {

    // Setup siblings array and get the first sibling
    var siblings = [];
    var sibling = elem.parentNode.firstChild;

    // Loop through each sibling and push to the array
    while (sibling) {
        if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling !== elem) {
            siblings.push(sibling);
        }
        sibling = sibling.nextSibling
    }

    return siblings;

};
```